# Multidimention Array combine with one array in javascript with specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, merge, array-merge

I have one array like below

```
[
 {
"__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
"uid": "MzY3",
"name": "AISLING BODYSUIT",
"crosssell_products": [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "uid": "NTI=",
    "name": "Product 1"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 2"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 3"
   }
  ]
 },
{
"__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
"uid": "MzI4",
"name": "CERYS BODYSUIT",
"crosssell_products": [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 4"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 5"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 6"
   }
 ]
}
]
```

I want single array with data which is contain crosssell_products array it means I want below format

```
 "crosssell_products": [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "uid": "NTI=",
    "name": "Product 1"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 2"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 3"
  },
   {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 4"
  },
   {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 5"
  },
   {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 6"
  },
]
```

I tried below code but not working

```
 let aa = getRelatedData?.products?.items.reduce(function (a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `flatMap()` Operator in javascript accomplish a flatten array.**

> Refer official documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
var arr = [
 {
"__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
"uid": "MzY3",
"name": "AISLING BODYSUIT",
"crosssell_products": [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "uid": "NTI=",
    "name": "Product 1"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 2"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 3"
   }
  ]
 },
{
"__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
"uid": "MzI4",
"name": "CERYS BODYSUIT",
"crosssell_products": [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 4"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 5"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 6"
   }
 ]
}
];


const results = arr.flatMap(v => v.crosssell_products);
console.log(results)
```

Comment: what is the difference between the first and your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). `map` will return an array of arrays, hence the need to use `flatMap` instead.

```
const res = getRelatedData.flatMap(el => el.crosssell_products);
console.log(res);
```

You can also use your method of iterating and reducing:

```
const res = getRelatedData.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el.crosssell_products), []);
console.log(res);
```

But `flatMap` is much more concise and illustrate the intent better.

```js
const getRelatedData = [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "uid": "MzY3",
    "name": "AISLING BODYSUIT",
    "crosssell_products": [
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "uid": "NTI=",
        "name": "Product 1"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 2"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 3"
       }
      ]
     },
    {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "uid": "MzI4",
    "name": "CERYS BODYSUIT",
    "crosssell_products": [
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 4"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 5"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 6"
       }
     ]
  }
];
const res = getRelatedData.flatMap(el => el.crosssell_products);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It is always preferred to add the code required code snippet first and then runnable code.

Comment: Thank you, @DecPK, appreciated the MDN reference, too. Good edits.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Array.flatMap()` as below

```
const flattenedCrossSellProducts = products.flatMap(product => product?.crosssell_products || []);
console.log(flattenedCrossSellProducts);
```

This will not fail, even if the `crosssell_products` not exist in the array or undefined.

```js
const products = [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "uid": "MzY3",
    "name": "AISLING BODYSUIT",
    "crosssell_products": [
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "uid": "NTI=",
        "name": "Product 1"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 2"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "uid": "MzI4",
    "name": "CERYS BODYSUIT",
    "crosssell_products": [
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 4"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 5"
      },
      {
        "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
        "name": "Product 6"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// Use flatMap to extract and flatten the crosssell_products arrays
const flattenedCrossSellProducts = products.flatMap(product => product?.crosssell_products || []);

console.log(flattenedCrossSellProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` to create a new array that contains only the `crosssell_products` arrays from each object in the original array.  Then,  `concat` it to combine these arrays into a single array and assign combined array to the `crosssell_products` property of a new object.

```js
let originalArray = [
 {
"__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
"uid": "MzY3",
"name": "AISLING BODYSUIT",
"crosssell_products": [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "uid": "NTI=",
    "name": "Product 1"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 2"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 3"
   }
  ]
 },
{
"__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
"uid": "MzI4",
"name": "CERYS BODYSUIT",
"crosssell_products": [
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 4"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 5"
  },
  {
    "__typename": "ConfigurableProduct",
    "name": "Product 6"
   }
 ]
}
]

let crosssellProductsArrays = originalArray.map(item => item.crosssell_products);
let combinedArray = [].concat(...crosssellProductsArrays);
let result = {
 "crosssell_products": combinedArray
};
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Flatmap does that in one go.